# Angular: Detect Logout after Server Restart

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I created an angular application that exposes a RESTful API and uses spring security (with LDAP) by using this [post](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) as reference and I managed to get it to work. The only problem is that if the server application (where the spring security is configured) is restarted all users are logged-out, but if the user leaves their browser page open they can navigate through the screens without a problem until they do something that would require access to the server.

So my question is: is there a way to automatically log-out the user or re-authenticate them when a server restart is detected (and how would one go about detecting such an event)?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Servlet should serialize all sessions to disk before shutdown, and reload them after restart. Make sure ALL session objects are Serializable

Comment: If your backend exposes a truely RESTful API then you won't need a session and the solution of MangEngkus is absolutely right

Comment: The backend does expose a RESTful API but it also handles authentication using Spring Security

Answer (score 1):

> to re-authenticate the user

you need stateless/sessionless API, consider using token based authentication, spring security OAuth has this. If you really need session, save it on the database not on your application server, spring session has this.

> to automatically log-out

the easy way is that if you angular try to access the server and it receive 401 forbidden from the server, then redirect the user to login page or popup window login. The user is automatically logout when the server is restarted, is just the client/angular doesn't aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to tackle this issue by implementing an interceptor as described in this [post](http://onehungrymind.com/winning-http-interceptors-angularjs/). I also implemented an `$interval` to detect that the user is unauthorised as soon as possible.